# Get the hours between the date time

Tags: mysql

I want to get the time in hours between two dateTime values  .
Lets say the motor engine is on and off at some time . Want to get the time in which the motor was on between two offs.
[table image displays motor ON and OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfg7C.png)

Comment: To post a table please use a `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT INTO` statements, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select TIMEDIFF('2018-10-17 15:02:14','2018-10-17 12:28:58')
you can get Hours/min/seconds too. 
If you need only hours use Select SUBSTRING_INDEX( TIMEDIFF('2018-10-17 15:02:14','2018-10-17 12:28:58'),':',1)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date1,date2);
```